# Left aligning text inside multicols environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, multicol

I am using the [`multicol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package. I was wondering if anyone knew how to correct the ugly looking spacing of words. It tries to align them so that each line takes up a column but that means some text will be spaced very widely apart and looks dumb. Is there a way to make it so that the text is not justified, and rather aligned to the left of the column?

[image]

As you can see some of the items in here are terribly spaced. Please help. Here is my code for reference.

```
\section{APPLICABLE \\ SKILLS}{\sl Educational and Practical Experience}
    \begin{multicols}{3}
    \begin{itemize} \itemsep -2pt
    \item SDS-PAGE
    \item Western Blot
    \item Antibody affinity chromatography
    \item Differential and Density gradient centrifugation
    \item Immunoprecipitation
    \item Genome sequencing
    \item Genomic analysis (copy number, SNP-detection, IGV, samtools, picard, etc.)
    \item Mass spec
    \item Bioinformatics
    \item Numerical analysis
    \item Software design
    \item High, medium, and low level programming design
    \item Linear algebra
    \item Graph theory
    \item Regression analysis
    \end{itemize}
    \end{multicols}
```

Comment: Use `\raggedright`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may use the `\raggedright` command (or the `\RaggedRight` variant of the [`ragged2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e) package which allows hyphenation) at the begin of a single `multicols` environment. You may also "patch" the `multicols` environment using `\AtBeginEnvironment` which is provided by the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{multicols}{\RaggedRight}

\begin{document}

\section{APPLICABLE \\ SKILLS}

{\slshape Educational and Practical Experience}

\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{itemize} \itemsep -2pt
\item SDS-PAGE
\item Western Blot
\item Antibody affinity chromatography
\item Differential and Density gradient centrifugation
\item Immunoprecipi\-tation
\item Genome sequencing
\item Genomic analysis (copy number, SNP-detection, IGV, samtools, picard, etc.)
\item Mass spec
\item Bioinformatics
\item Numerical analysis
\item Software design
\item High, medium, and low level programming design
\item Linear algebra
\item Graph theory
\item Regression analysis
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: As pointed out by egreg, another possibility is to define a new `raggedmulticols` environment (use it like `multicols` in the document body):

```
\newenvironment{raggedmulticols}[1]{%
  \RaggedRight
  \begin{multicols}{#1}%
}{%
  \end{multicols}%
}
```

Comment: I would define a `raggedmulticols` environment, rather than acting globally on `multicols`.

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: Cool the raggedright thing works! The solution with etoolbox is beautiful. Although I am not quite sure how it works, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

If this is specifically for lists, you could also use [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) with `multicol` to have the list in columns. The example below is taken from the manual of `enumitem` (Chapter 9, *Generic keys and values*).

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\SetEnumitemKey{threecol}{
itemsep=1\itemsep,
parsep=1\parsep,
before=\raggedcolumns\begin{multicols}{3}\RaggedRight,
after=\end{multicols}}

\begin{document}
\section{APPLICABLE \\ SKILLS}{\sl Educational and Practical Experience}
    \begin{itemize}[threecol] \itemsep -2pt
    \item SDS-PAGE
    \item Western Blot
    \item Antibody affinity chromatography
    \item Differential and Density gradient centrifugation
    \item Immunoprecipi\-tation
    \item Genome sequencing
    \item Genomic analysis (copy number, SNP-detection, IGV, samtools, picard, etc.)
    \item Mass spec
    \item Bioinformatics
    \item Numerical analysis
    \item Software design
    \item High, medium, and low level programming design
    \item Linear algebra
    \item Graph theory
    \item Regression analysis
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```