# Left align figure in multicols environment in baposter

Tags: multicol, baposter

I have already seen [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44322/shifting-figure-to-the-left-in-beamer) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58509/flush-to-the-left-align-environment-in-beamer?rq=1) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48281/left-aligning-text-inside-multicols-environment) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/536692/add-a-figure-in-multicol-environment-latex).

I have one section of a baposter:

```
\headerbox{Results - Base Model Performance}{name=performance,column=1,span=2,row=0}{

\begin{multicols}{2}
Text here about base model performance. This is the entire column.

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Fig3b}
\end{center}

\end{multicols}
```

I cannot use a `\figure` inside a the `multicols` environment, because I get a compilation error. Originally, I had:

```
\begin{figure}\flushleft
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Fig3b}
\end{figure}
```

But of course that wouldn't compile.

How can I align the figure to the left of the column?

Comment: Please provide an MWE which reproduce your problem. From codes fragment is not seen, what is going wrong.

Comment: Try adding more text after the image.  Right now there is nothing to fill the second column EXCEPT the image.  Also, [width=\columnwidth] is more reliable then [scale=0.5].